# how can i get all the data from my model booking having date less than today i want to show the booking history of customer

Tags: django, date, django-views, django-filters

view.py 
def Profile(request,uid):

```
book =booking.objects.filter(user=uid)
user =User.objects.get(id=uid)
books = booking.objects.filter(created__lt=datetime.today(),user=uid)

params={'book':book,'user':user,'books':books}
return render(request, 'hotel/userProfile.html',params)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `book` variable is already filtering on `user=uid` to get all bookings for the user, try filtering that result set further to limit the dates:

```
user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
book = booking.objects.filter(user=user)
books = book.filter(created__lt=datetime.date.today())
```

(Note the change from `datetime.today()` to `datetime.date.today()`)

You can also use Django's `_set` context to get all the books for a user instead of explicitly using `filter` (Django will automatically create a related name as the name of the referenced model with a suffix of `_set` that you can use to grab all related objects - in your case, it would be called `booking_set`):

```
user = User.objects.get(id=uid)
books = user.booking_set.all()
```

As an aside, using `filter` on a queryset object just returns another queryset, so you can chain them together. So you could do something like this if you wanted:

`books = User.objects.get(id=uid).booking_set.all().filter(created__lt=datetime.date.today())`

You should read this section of the docs, it will explain all of the mechanics of saving and retrieving records from the DB: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/db/queries/

Answer (score -1):

```
        def Profile(request,uid):   
         user =User.objects.get(id=uid) #this displays user information in profile
         books = booking.objects.filter(date__gte=datetime.today(),user=uid) #displays booking date greater than equal to today
         book = booking.objects.filter(date__lt=datetime.today(),user=uid) #displays booking date greater than eqaul to today
         params={'book':book,'user':user,'books':books}
         return render(request, 'hotel/userProfile.html',params)
```

this can be done by the above method also !! yes, little lengthy but works for me.

Comment: You're duplicating the same exact filter in books and book...why? You should strive to avoid useless/duplicated code in your programs...